# In Pandemic, can the Containment Specialist remove more than 1 cube (without the action of treating) in a cured city?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-on-the-brink

In Pandemic, when there are 2 or 3 cubes of the same color on a cured city, does the Containment Specialist remove only 1 cube when he lands or all of the cubes (like when treating) since it is cured?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key verb here is **treat**.

From the [game base rules](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/pandemic.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> **Treat** Disease:
>
> Remove 1 disease cube from the city you are in, placing it in the cube
>   supply next to the board. If this disease color has been cured (see
>   Discover a Cure below), remove all cubes of that color from the city you
>   are in.

The Medic can remove all cubes from a cured disease simply by entering it but it's his role privilege, other roles still have to spend a second action to cure all the cubes

> MEDIC
>
> The Medic removes all cubes, not 1, of the same color
>   when doing the **Treat** Disease action.
>   If a disease has been cured, he automatically removes
>   all cubes of that color from a city, simply by entering it
>   or being there. This does not take an action.

For instance, the containment specialist drives to Atlanta where there are 3 blue cubes (1 action). By doing so, he removes a cube for free, but only one since it's not a **Treat** action. Then he **treats** the blue disease thus removing the remaining two cubes (1 action)

> CONTAINMENT SPECIALIST
>
> When you enter a city with 2 or more cubes of the same color, **remove** 1 cube

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: I've looked and can't see where to "accept the answer." I had already clicked "answer is useful." Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: If you look the answers to a question *you*'ve asked, there are 3 buttons on the left: a Up arrow (the one you clicked, thanks for that ;-)) ; the down arrow if the answer was not useful and a "check" button to accept the answer if it solved your problem. The check button doesn't show up on answers on other peoples' questions...

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks for letting me know how to play the game. :)

Comment: No problem! Thanks for playing it ;-) BTW, there's a quick tour that you can take. It will show you the ropes (and you'll get a badge for that ;-)): http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

> CONTAINMENT SPECIALIST
>
> When you *enter* a city with 2 or more disease cubes of the same color, remove 1 of them.

Upon entering the city with two or more cubes of the same color, the Containment Specialist removes 1 of those cubes - that's it.

This ability has nothing to do with treating the disease.

In particular it doesn't care whether the disease is cured or not.